# p:inputText in p:dialog return empty values to bean

Tags: java, primefaces

I'm trying get a value from a p:inputText is inside a p:dialog but this is returning null to my bean.
The inputText motivoCancelamento needs to be filled with the content of my inputText motivoCancelamentoDialog inside the dialog. 
The another ones are ok, like status, protocoloCancelamento and dataCancelamento. 
Can anyone help me?

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:toolbar>
                <f:facet name="left">
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>                          
                    <p:dialog header="Cancelar Nota" widgetVar="cancelamentoDialog" focus="motivoCancelamentoDialog">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                            <h:outputLabel for="motivoCancelamentoDialog" value="Motivo Cancelamento:" />
                            <p:inputText id="motivoCancelamentoDialog" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" actionListener="#{notaProdutoBean.cancelarNota()}" update="status motivoCancelamento protocoloCancelamento dataCancelamento messages form"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>   
                    </p:dialog>
                    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                        <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                    </p:confirmDialog>
            </p:toolbar>                
            <p:fieldset id='panelNotaFiscal' legend="NotaFiscal" >
                <p:panelGrid columns="6" columnClasses="centered">
                    <p:outputLabel for='status' value='Status'/>
                    <p:inputText id="status" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.status}" required="true" requiredMessage="O campo Status é obrigatório">              
                        <p:message for="status"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel for="motivoCancelamento" value="Motivo Cancelamento"/>
                    <p:inputText id="motivoCancelamento" size="25" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}">
                        <p:message for="motivoCancelamento"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel for="protocoloCancelamento" value="Protocolo Cancelamento"/>
                    <p:inputText id="protocoloCancelamento" size="15" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.protocoloCancelamento}">
                        <p:message for="protocoloCancelamento"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel for="dataCancelamento" value="Data Cancelamento"/>
                    <p:calendar id="dataCancelamento" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.dataCancelamento}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
                        <p:message for='dataCancelamento'/>
                    </p:calendar>                       
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
```

```
public void cancelarNota(){
    try{
        if(getNotaProduto().getStatus().equals("Autorizada")){
            getNotaProduto().setStatus("Cancelada");
            System.out.println("Motivo " + getNotaProduto().getMotivoCancelamento());
            getNotaProduto().setProtocoloCancelamento("22222222222222");
            getNotaProduto().setDataCancelamento(new Date());
            new BaseBean().salvar(getNotaProduto());
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('cancelamentoDialog').hide();");
        }
        else{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO ,"Mensagem: ", "A nota não está autorizada portanto não pode ser cancelada"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        new Log().salvaErroLog(e);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR ,"Mensagem: ", "Um erro ocorreu, entre em conto com o adminstrador"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 inputs for the same field in the same form:

```
<p:inputText id="motivoCancelamentoDialog" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}" />

<p:inputText id="motivoCancelamento" size="25" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}">
                        <p:message for="motivoCancelamento"/>
                    </p:inputText>
```

you should put the dialog in a separate form so it doesnt post the second input.

also you can specify the elements to process in the "cancelar" button

```
<p:inputText id="motivoCancelamentoDialog" value="# notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}" />
<p:commandButton value="Cancelar" actionListener="#{notaProdutoBean.cancelarNota()}" update="status motivoCancelamento protocoloCancelamento dataCancelamento messages form" process="@this, motivoCancelamentoDialog"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

your input tag is actually empty tag 
`<p:inputText id="motivoCancelamentoDialog" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}" />`
try using something like below to see if it works.
`<p:inputText id="motivoCancelamentoDialog" value="#{notaProdutoBean.notaProduto.motivoCancelamento}">abc</p:inputText>`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but sorry, this answer is completely wrong.